# FMU from Simulink model can't handle inputs?

Tags: fmi

I have been working on a way to export models from Simulink to a FMU, which we will open source when we have a not-so-buggy version. Me and a collegue finally got a working version and extracted our first FMU from just a zip.

As it turns out, we must be doing something wrong within the program. Our FMU works fine, except for inputs. None of the inputs seem to be working. This have been tested mutliple times, like having a constant go to an out, which works, and I have also tested working FMUs made from our other non-open-source software and they work. I just can't seem to find what is different from theirs to ours FMU.

[Here is a dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/166j0bfe8qxd2xw/AADIauVJUpONBf-45MYAXafLa?dl=0) if anyone wants the source of the test FMU. The model is simple, with one input going straight towards the output and one output getting fed from a constant. Currently, I can read the one output getting a constant, but not the input one. It's always 0. The dropbox folder includes the generated zip file from the model, the model.slx file, the generated FMU and also a folder containing everything inside the FMU. I know we aren't including all sources inside the FMU just yet, but I will fix that when we find out what our issue is with the FMU's. The sources exist inside the zip, so nothing is left out.

If anyone with experience around FMI has had this issue before or maybe have a clue what we could be doing wrong, I would be so greateful if you could share your experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue by changing the FMUSDK fmuTemplate.c file to call functions and handle my own inputs and outputs instead.